# Font in w3layout template

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to web design and would be grateful to get some help here. I found this[template](http://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/bloom-portfolio-single-page-responsive-website-template/) and hoped to use it, but I need it to show extended Latin so i need it to show letters like čšř etc.. I've tried to modify the CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,900,300&subset=latin,latin-ext);
```

and modify the html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,900,300&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

but it still shows ???? symbols

can you help me please?

Comment: Your template have [meta charset utf-8](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp)?

Comment: yes it has, i added it there but it is still the same

Comment: now i am putting that letters there by html unicode like &ccaron for č, but it is really uncomfortable. If there is no solution then i will have to use this.. :(